# Graficar array de coordenadas con chart js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

Llevo días tratando de graficar (lineal) un array de coordenadas mediante chart js, pero no consigo que me lea el formato con el que debería graficar.
Si coloco datos manualmente funciona bien (como muestra la linea comentada).

```
function graficaDiaria(){
    var f1 = $('#fecha').val();
    var f2 = $('#fecha2').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'infRecepGrafDiario.php',
        data: {"f1":f1, "f2":f2}
    }).done(function(data){
        var fechas = [];
        var cPaloma = [];           
        var data = JSON.parse(data);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < data[i][0].length; j++) {
                fechas.push(data[i][0][j]);
                cPaloma.push(data[i][1][j]);                                        
            }           
        }
         
        console.table(cPaloma);
        
        var ctx = document.getElementById('totalxdia').getContext('2d');

        var paloma = {
            label: "Paloma",
            data: [cPaloma],
            //data: [{x:'2020-12-11', y:5000},{x:'2020-12-12', y:0},{x:'2020-12-14', y:0},{x:'2020-12-15', y:35000}],
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
        }
        

        var resultado = {
            labels: fechas,
            datasets: [paloma]
        }

        var lineas = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: resultado,
            options: {                  
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Totales Cerezas Diario'
                }
             }                          
        });
    });             
}
```

En la consola obtengo lo siguiente de mi array cPaloma, pero el gráfico sigue en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Y cómo estás intentando graficar? Sólo vemos una variable inicializada con datos.

Comment: Hola, por favor comparte que tipo de chart estas usando y como se muestra tu chart actualmente con el código que compartiste.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta.

Comment: pon un console log de tu objeto cPaloma, para ver si te lo esta detectando como objetos cada ítem, o como un string.

Comment: Y de paso un console.log de lo que te regresa la petición en data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto pasa porque, a simple vista, se nota que la respuesta que obtienes desde `infRecepGrafDiario.php` está mal formada.

Lo que tú necesitas es un array de **objetos**:

```
[{x:'2020-12-11', y:5000},{x:'2020-12-12', y:0},{x:'2020-12-14', y:0},{x:'2020-12-15', y:35000}]
```

Lo que está siendo retornado desde tu endpoint es un array de **strings**:

```
[
   "{x:'2020-12-11',y:5000}",
   "{x:'2020-12-12',y:0}",
   "{x:'2020-12-13',y:0}",
   "{x:'2020-12-14',y:3500}",
]
```

Por lo que la solución sería convertir dicho array de strings a uno con objetos. La respuesta sería simple, si lo que estuviese dentro de ese string fuese un [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), pero no lo es, por lo que se complica un poco.

Dado que el formato es homogéneo, es decir, siempre habrá una `x:...` y un `y:...`, puedes usar [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) para obtener los valores y armes cada objeto manualmente:

```
const newArray = data.map(item => {
    let pointX = item.match(/(?<=x:)(\'.*?\')/gm);
    let pointY = item.match(/(?<=y:)(.*?)(?=})/gm);
  
    return {
        x: pointX[0].replaceAll("'", ''),
        y: pointY[0]
    };
});
```

Obviamente, las soluciones pueden variar, esta es sólo una, para entender esta solución necesitas entender cómo funcionan los [assertions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions).

```
(?<=foo:) => Lookbehind assertion
(?=foo)   => Lookahead assertion
```

Básicamente, lo que hace la expresión regular es:

```
(?<=x:) Buscar después de x: y además que esté entre comillas simples (\'.*?\')
```

Igual para la segunda expresión regular, sólo que esta vez buscará entre `y:` y `}`.

Aquí te dejo un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yavoz2re/).

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba, creo que nunca hubiera podido dar con la solución.